# Access to iPhone's BlueTooth Abilities via SDK?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Is there a way to use Bluetooth from the iPhone SDK?  I have some cool ideas for apps involving bluetooth, but I haven't turned up anything searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope! You could file a bug report, but that's little more than a far off wish right now. Figure out how to implement your ideas with WiFi Bonjour networking instead.

Comment: So basically, you can only connect 2 devices over bluetooth bonjour, more with wifi bonjour? Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer these days is *maybe* with the 3.0 OS.

The thing is it seems the APIs do not allow full control of the bluetooth hardware. Rather you get packaged *uses* like sending packets to another iPhone for peer-to-peer gaming.

This probably means we won't be seeing VOIP applications with bluetooth headset support, which is a real shame.